# Ajax does not send a variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to send variable from JS and use it in PHP code. I wrote this function and downloaded it in PHP. It doesn't work, why?

```
$("#gen").on("click", function () {

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "file.php";

    var test = "data="+document.getElementById("test").value;


    request.open("POST",url,true);

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", test.length);


    request.onreadystatechange=checkResult;

    request.send(test);

    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

});

<form method="post" action="file.php">
```

I downloaded variable this way:

```
$test = $_POST['test'];
```

Here is the link of my code :- [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/rBKXbG3t)

Comment: how about using `$test = $_POST['data'];` - since you send `"data="`

Comment: use jquery ajax to send variable,or $test = $_POST['data']

Comment: use print_r($_POST) to get the index.

Comment: `use jquery` - like using a sledgehammer to put up a picture hook

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ Care to explain what happens? Nothing? Errors?

Comment: I received Undefined index: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\generator kart\file.php on line 17

Comment: @JaromandaX Since the OP already uses jQuery, why not do the ajax request with it as well?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - true dat - didn't even notice the `$` and there was no jQuery tag - still would fail as the server code was where the error was :p

Comment: What is `#gen`? Is that a submit button in your form? How do you check the response? Is your above ajax even triggered or are you actually posting the form "normally" (the page reloads)?  Asking since you don't have any `event.preventDefault()` in the click-callback and you get different POST keys from what the above code actually posts.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, the entire page code is generated in JS, #gen summarize the form, as you say - it can include whole PHP. I'm pretty fresh in here, so these errors: https://pastebin.com/78m6S3VF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342956/ajax-does-not-send-a-variable-to-php#comment77649031_45343204) comment:

You don't need any JavaScript to accomplish "post and redirect in one go".

Simply use your `<input type="submit" id="gen" value="Generate" />` as it is and it should POST all data in the form to your PHP file. If you need other variables to be passed to your server, make a few `<input type="hidden">` fields on your page and make their `value`s your JS variables (using `$("#input-id").val(yourVariable);` )

---

**This Code answers the initial question**

The Error in your Client-Side Code:

You specifically used the `type` `submit` in this button `<input type="submit" id="gen" value="Generate" />`. What that does is tell the browser to stop everything and submit the nearest form. If you instead want to do something else with a button you have to use

```
$("#gen").on("click", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "file.php";

    var test = "data="+document.getElementById("test").value;


    request.open("POST",url,true);

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", test.length);


    request.onreadystatechange=checkResult;

    request.send(test);

    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

});
```

`e.preventDefault();` tells your browser not to do what it was instructed to do by the `type="submit` but rather run your js code.

The others are right you can get your data using `$test = $_POST["data"];`. Here's why:

When sending your Data you build a `x-www-form-urlencoded` string (this one: `"data="+document.getElementById("test").value;`).

To you and to your connection, this is simply a String that gets appended to your request, but your Server (your `file.php`) interprets this as an associative array, meaning a Data Structure with a `key` (data) and a `value` (`document.getElementById("test").value`). When you submit a form your browser does this automatically, it appends all data in the form to your request and sends it to the server that way.

Every request with added data follows this pattern. When you take a look at YouTube for Example, their video-urls all contian `?v=...`. If you wanted to built YouTube in PHP you would get the variable using `$video = $_GET["v"]`.

Comment: I did as you said, but now after clicking #gen totally nothing happens, although the path to the file is ok.

Comment: what do you mean with "nothing happens"?

Comment: your site shouldn't reload if you meant that

Comment: I wanted to get the following effect: After clicking generate the page reloads and redirects to file.php and at that moment sends the variables from JS to PHP, which I can later call in JS.

If my thinking is wrong and there is some other way, please let me correct you. I'm just starting and I do not want to learn bad habits from the beginning.

Comment: What you did was make it so, that your data gets send to your php file in the background. If you want to be redirected to that page, you don't need any javascript at all

Comment: simply use one input of `type="submit` and you should be good to go.

Comment: The problem is that in JS there are variables that I need to use in PHP, such as width or height of items dynamically generated on the page: /

Comment: I am currently working on editing my answer again ;)

Comment: @unknown_dude try that. You should mention this in your question next time :P

Comment: I see progress, I sit on that third day and finally the board showed this variable, but there is one more problem. I do not know if I could write everything well and get it, because PHP theoretically read that I sent something, but the value of the variable was not received. Link: https://pastebin.com/bCfzVxck

Comment: I love you man! :D I find two errors in my code. I did not set id and in jquery declaration i hasn't # IT WORKS!

Comment: nice to hear that, and thanks for accepting my answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this Code:

```
$test = $_POST['data'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get data in post request using `$_POST['data']`.

Because you are sending it in `data`.

So,change your code like this,

```
$test = $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: I introduced your changes 

$test = $_POST['data'];
echo $test;

I received Undefined index: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\generator kart\file.php on line 17, why?

Comment: use `print_r($_POST);` what you are getting in your array?

Comment: Array ( [k-title] => [k-desc] => )

Comment: that's strange. Can you add your HTML to your Question? It seems like the button does something else than execute the js

Comment: @unknown_dude Are you showing us the correct code in your question? That code can't post the array your claiming to get.

Comment: @unknown_dude You're actually posting the form normally, and not through your ajax. One sign is that the page reloads...

Comment: So why your input type is `submit` ? It will refresh page make it button.